# Android: MySQL database SQL statements

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables. One table storing the user details and the other stores the files created by the user. I am now trying to save the userid, filename and moddate into the files table.

users table contains: `userid, unique_id( hashed value ), username`

files table contains: `id, userid, filename, moddate`

I could get hold of the `unique_id` value and i used the sql statement below to get the userid from the users table.

```
$id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT userid FROM users WHERE unique_id= '$userid'");


 $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO files(userid, name, mod_date) VALUES('$id','$name', NOW())");
```

But the userid value added in files table in the database keeps having the value 0. Did i do it the right way? Is the Insert statement correct?

Correction:

```
$id = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT userid FROM users WHERE unique_id= '$userid'");

$rowid = mysqli_fetch_row($id);


    $result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO file_info(userid, name, mod_date) VALUES('$rowid','$name', NOW())");
```

Comment: May I confirm if this question is related to Android or pure PHP?

Comment: First you get whole row data and then extract userid and try to use this way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysqli_query` will not return the selected id. It returns the `mysqli_result` object. You have to use `mysqli_fetch_xxx` functions to fetch the rows and get data from them. See the example here: http://www.php.net/manual/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php
Look at this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE unique_id = '$userid'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

if ($row){
    $id = $row[0];
    ...
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO file_info (userid, name, mod_date)  VALUES('$id','$name', NOW())");    
}
```

Comment: I have added the correction portion above. Do i do it this way?

Comment: No, mysqli_fetch_row returns table row as array. You have to use: $rowid[0] to get the ID, but I would also recommend to rename your variables according to their real meaning.